# How to speed up java.net.ServerSocket and java.net.Socket efficiency?

Tags: java, sockets, performance

I wonder what are the limits of java.net.ServerSocket and java.net.Socket in request per second. I write some simply test code (multithreaded too) and find limit about 1200 requests per second on my machine (test on double core processor, 64bit linux and 32bit windows).

Is there solution for java to increase ratio per second several thousand? Is JVM overhead to big to for several thousands ratio?

I want to mention that I realize java use native code for this part of code and tests are OS dependent (configuration and implementation).

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to say without looking at your code.

On the one hand, there are things that your application could be doing that would make network I/O (indeed all I/O) slow.  For example, reading or writing an unbuffered stream / reader one byte at a time.  It is also possible that there is a lot of thread switching going on.  Or maybe you should be using NIO to get better throughput.

On the other hand, the slowness might be due to high network latency, low network bandwidth or congestion ... or an OS networking stack that is not particularly good.

Or it could be something else.

Comment: +1. I was getting 1000 requests/second ten years ago. You must be doing something wrong. And ServerSocket doesn't have much to do with it: all you have to do with it is accept connections and start threads. Of course if you have excss baggage in your accept() loop it will slow everything down. Code please.

Answer (score 2):

Over loop back you should be able to achieve up to 50K requests per second (assuming the request is trivial)  I suggest you try this to see what it is for your machine.  As @Stephen C suggests, other factors such as what the request does and the network characteristics will make much more difference.